# Coldfusion cfset date in variable

Tags: date, coldfusion

I saw a similar post but not exactly what I am trying to accomplish.

**All I want to do is save the current date and time in a variable that I can add to a database table. But when the form submits I get a 500 Server page error**

Below is my code so far:

```
<cfif isDefined("FORM.submit") AND #FORM.submit# IS NOT "">
    <cfoutput>
        <cfset var submit_date = #DateFormat(Now(),"mm/dd/yy - HH:mm:ss")#>
        <cfquery name="InsertSuggestion" datasource="MainDB">
            INSERT INTO Suggestion_Form (Submission_Date,Submission_Content)
            VALUES      ('#submit_date#','#FORM.suggestion_text#')
        </cfquery>
    </cfoutput>
    <div style="text-align:center;width:100%;">We value your feedback. Your request has been recieved.</div>  
<cfelse>
```

Comment: FYI: the `#` in `AND #FORM.submit# IS NOT` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your RDBMS has something that returns the current date and time, I suggest using it.  In sql server for example, your query becomes:

```
INSERT INTO Suggestion_Form 
(Submission_Date
,Submission_Content
)
VALUES      
(getdate()
, <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#FORM.suggestion_text#">
)
```

If you want to submit something from ColdFusion, just submit now().

```
VALUES      
(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#now()#">
```

Not related to your question, but I also added a query parameter tag which gives you many benefits.  Also, the format I used, 1 field per line with commas on the left makes it easier to comment things out if you have to troubleshoot.

Comment: please don't send unparameterized form scoped variables into SQL queries.  Use cfqueryparam http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c36.html

Comment: As an aside, whichever method you use, be consistent. In cases where the db server is on a different machine than the CF server, `getDate()` and `now()` may return different results. So either use one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Mysql, You are sending date in wrong format. MySql stores date in yy/mm/dd format. So if you change the 
`<cfset var submit_date = #DateFormat(Now(),"mm/dd/yy - HH:mm:ss")#>` 
 to
 `<cfset var submit_date = #DateFormat(Now(),"YY/MM/DD - HH:mm:ss")#>.`
It should work fine.

Comment: Mysql, like all databases, stores dates as dates.  Format is for display purposes.  Given that DateFormat returns a string, using it to create a value for a date field might work, but is not the best method.

Comment: @DanBracuk, If you check the documentation of MySql. It clearly states that "The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format and the DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format."
Please check 1st and 2nd paragraph http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: @DanBracuk, Also If you search for '“relaxed” format'(without single quote). You will find example which clearly demonstrates that MySql stores dates in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: *MySql stores date in yy/mm/dd format* No. [Date/time values are stored as numbers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html), not strings! The problem with using *strings* in sql is it relies upon implicit conversion and the individual settings for that specific database instance. So it may - or may not - interpret the string correctly. Not to mention, it may behave differently on another database which has different settings. For consistent and reliable results, date/time values should be passed to the database as date *objects*, not strings.

Comment: @TusharBhaware you need to understand the difference between what the DB stores data as, and what it - using your own words - "retrieves and displays" them as. Those are two different things. Java apps (like ColdFusion) connect to the MySQL DB via JDBC, and it's best to pass JDBC the object type it's actually expecting - a date / date/time. CFML code can pass a string, but then CF needs to convert it to an object anyhow, and ambiguities can creep in then. Best to just stick to using the write data type for the job.

Comment: @TusharBhaware, I notice that the format you mentioned in your comments about how MySQL displays dates and times is different than the one you recommend in your answer.  But the OP did not specify his database engine so it might all be irrelevant for this question.  Even if it was MySQL, using the ColdFusion datatype that matches the database datatype is still a better idea.

Comment: @DanBracuk,Yes, Your way is better than mine. That is why i voted up your answer. In my first comment, I stated from the documents that how Mysql retrieves and dispalyes DATE. In my second comment, i stated a example from the doc itself which gave me impression that DATE is stored in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format and when i tried this on my local machine, it worked, it stored data in my MySql database. I guess i got end result right but not in most appropriate way but leigh's and adam's comment clear things up for me. Thanks all for commenting here.

Comment: One other note about the code above.  `DateFormat(Now(),"mm/dd/yy - HH:mm:ss")` will not work. At least not completely. As the name implies, that function is only intended to handle "dates". For some reason it allows "HH" and "ss". However, "mm" always returns the month number and NOT the number of minutes. To handle times, use TimeFormat() or the new DateTimeFormat() function instead. Also, "yy" is ambiguous. Best to use four digit years "yyyy".